# jQuery .remove() - understanding its use

Tags: jquery

`.remove()`

Would this remove, for example a textbox, completely from a form and therefore the form would act as if it were not there in the first place?

The following describes it at: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

But I don't want to assume I am correct.

Comment: Yes, but the best test is to try it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.remove()` removes the element and everything inside it from the DOM.

So yes, it will remove your textbox from the form.

Example: `$('.my-textbox').remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

But note that `:remove` would be a CSS selector (if it existed), instead, it's a method of jQuery objects: `.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should provide you with plenty of information regarding the .remove() jQuery element!

[W3Schools' .Remove() Coverage](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [`remove` method](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) removes the element from the DOM.

Sometimes when you take an item out of the DOM, you want to add it somewhere else in the DOM. Then you would use the [`detatch` method](http://api.jquery.com/detach/). The `remove` method doesn't only take the element out of the DOM, it also removes all data that jQuery might have associated with it.

Either `remove` or `detatch` would take the element out of the DOM, so that it's not part of the form at all.